# Javascript/Excel non-linear X axis/different scale

Tags: javascript, excel

Is there any way to replicate the graph on the left in Excel?

If not, any way to do it in JavaScript/Python? The upper scale on the X axis is different than lower scale (it's stretched).

[image: Excel Graphs]

Comment: [Excel chart with two X-axes (horizontal), possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/188064/excel-chart-with-two-x-axes-horizontal-possible) on [the Super User Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Search on `c.g. envelope js chart` such as https://github.com/cvializ/wab or https://trumpetb.net/alph/.